# AngularJS loads index.html instead of template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache

I'm having troubles with an app when loaded on my deployment server.

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.x and following the scheme proposed by Angular-Seed template for routing and configuration: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Everything works fine on local (Apache) and on another remote web server (Apache) (a free hosting service). Routing works and pages load like expected. In the remote server i can experience some little hangs when loading a template not loaded before but i think it's normal.

The problem is on my official deployment server (Apache):
Instead of loading routes templates it load recursively the index.html inside it self resulting in an stack exceeded error from the browser after few seconds and the halting of the page.

Sometimes it doesn't and load the page like expected, but after two or three routes it start loading index.html recursively instead of the template requested.
In most cases, however, at the first route triggered by link or event the page hangs loading recursively index.html inside itself.

Like in angular-seed i have a single index.html with a `<div ng-view></div>` tag for content.

No problem on local and in the another free web server.

I've tried even to use ui.router and his states pattern instead of ng-router.

No more stack exceeded because after the first index.html loaded inside index.html at the `<div ng-view>` it stops the recursion.

With ui.router, still no problem in local or in the other free web server. The app do what expected loading all the states/route.

There is some apache configuration or something i must check on the server?

The deployment server is a dedicated server so i can have access to everything.

Thanks for help!

EDIT:

Here Apache modules of the three server:

**Local server Apache modules:**
core
http_core
mod_access_compat
mod_actions
mod_alias
mod_allowmethods
mod_auth_basic
mod_auth_digest
mod_auth_form
mod_authn_anon
mod_authn_core
mod_authn_dbd
mod_authn_dbm
mod_authn_file
mod_authn_socache
mod_authnz_ldap
mod_authz_core
mod_authz_dbd
mod_authz_dbm
mod_authz_groupfile
mod_authz_host
mod_authz_owner
mod_authz_user
mod_autoindex
mod_bucketeer
mod_buffer
mod_cache
mod_cache_disk
mod_case_filter
mod_case_filter_in
mod_cern_meta
mod_cgi
mod_cgid
mod_charset_lite
mod_dav
mod_dav_fs
mod_dbd
mod_deflate
mod_dir
mod_dumpio
mod_echo
mod_env
mod_expires
mod_ext_filter
mod_file_cache
mod_filter
mod_headers
mod_include
mod_info
mod_lbmethod_bybusyness
mod_lbmethod_byrequests
mod_lbmethod_bytraffic
mod_lbmethod_heartbeat
mod_log_config
mod_log_debug
mod_logio
mod_mime
mod_mime_magic
mod_negotiation
mod_perl
mod_php5
mod_proxy
mod_proxy_ajp
mod_proxy_balancer
mod_proxy_connect
mod_proxy_express
mod_proxy_fcgi
mod_proxy_ftp
mod_proxy_http
mod_proxy_scgi
mod_ratelimit
mod_remoteip
mod_reqtimeout
mod_request
mod_rewrite
mod_sed
mod_session
mod_session_cookie
mod_session_dbd
mod_setenvif
mod_slotmem_shm
mod_so
mod_socache_dbm
mod_socache_memcache
mod_socache_shmcb
mod_speling
mod_ssl
mod_status
mod_substitute
mod_suexec
mod_unique_id
mod_unixd
mod_userdir
mod_usertrack
mod_version
mod_vhost_alias
prefork
util_ldap

**Remote server Apache modules:**
core
http_core
mod_actions
mod_alias
mod_asis
mod_auth_basic
mod_authn_default
mod_authn_file
mod_authz_default
mod_authz_groupfile
mod_authz_host
mod_authz_user
mod_av_htaccess
mod_cgi
mod_deflate
mod_dir
mod_env
mod_expires
mod_fastcgi
mod_filter
mod_include
mod_log_config
mod_logio
mod_mime
mod_negotiation
mod_php5
mod_rewrite
mod_setenvif
mod_so
mod_status
mod_version
mod_vhost_alias
parser
prefork

**Production server Apache modules:**
core
http_core
mod_actions
mod_alias
mod_auth_basic
mod_authn_default
mod_authn_file
mod_authz_default
mod_authz_groupfile
mod_authz_host
mod_authz_user
mod_autoindex
mod_cgi
mod_dir
mod_env
mod_expires
mod_filter
mod_headers
mod_include
mod_log_config
mod_logio
mod_mime
mod_negotiation
mod_proxy
mod_proxy_ajp
mod_proxy_balancer
mod_proxy_connect
mod_proxy_ftp
mod_proxy_http
mod_proxy_scgi
mod_rewrite
mod_setenvif
mod_so
mod_ssl
mod_status
mod_suexec
mod_unique_id
mod_userdir
prefork

Could be the lack of `mod_vhost_alias` be related to issue?
I've read that `mod_userdir` will overwrite `mod_vhost_alias` but it's the only module missing in my production server that concern resolution of files and that is present on local and remote free configuration...

I'll try to rebuild apache and include that module in the next few days and then test.

Comment: clearly a server configuration problem

Comment: I've seen that happen whenever an html templateUrl is incorrect, because when the app can't find the template it defers to the router and when there is no route defined for that path the app is typically set up to redirect to the home page. Most likely, your production server doesn't like the relative path you're giving for your html templates. Check that the application root is what you think it is, and that template paths are accessible to the web. Could be a server permission issue.

Comment: Sometimes file are loaded, sometimes not. If i put the full path i can get into the template pages. So what permissions i have to check? Could be some apache cache module or something?

Comment: I say that because if i visit directly the html template file before requesting it by a route it loads correctly. If not, it start with the recursive index.html loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some checking by the support team of my hosting provider we have identified the problem.

It was related to some false positive matching by ModSecurity apache module.

I had to disable following rules id:

```
981242
981243
981245
981246
981257
```

And this maybe not strictly related rule that got triggered during testing:

```
970901
```

All rules are related to MySQL injection preventing.

Now app works as expected.

Hope it can be of anyhelp for someone.

Thank you all for support, tips and advices!